# What should I write instead of "whom he or she wants to participate"?

Tags: phrase-request, phrases

I have a project and documentation for it.

My command writes "[…] whom he or she wants to participate […]."

Is it correct to write *he or she*, or should I write another word, such as *user*, *person*, or *human*?

Is there any difference between American English and other English dialects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't show the rest of the sentence, so I cannot say if it should be *who* or *whom*, but you don't need to write *he or she*. Just write "who[m]ever wants to participate."

*Whomever* is used as object of a verb or preposition; *whoever* is used as subject of the sentence.

> He was free to marry **whomever** he chose.

> **Whoever** says that is a liar.

In your case, it could be, for example:

> Whoever wants to participate is free to do it.

> We welcome whomever wants to participate.